# PyInstaller --onefile is throwing file not found error

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe, command-prompt, executable

I am trying to make an executable of a python 3.10 file using PyInstaller in the command prompt:

```
python -m PyInstaller --onefile 1.0.py
```

with "1.0" being my file name. I have done this many times before on the same PC and with the same python version, but for this file it is throwing a "file specified not found" error:

```
  while run_next_command(read_fh, write_fh):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 188, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 178, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 59, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 934, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 856, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "E:\Python Scripts\High Spen\Combined\1.0.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 381, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 173, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 660, in assemble
    isolated.call(find_binary_dependencies, list(self.binaries), self.binding_redirects, collected_packages)
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated\_parent.py", line 238, in call
    return isolated.call(function, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated\_parent.py", line 176, in call
    raise RuntimeError(f"Child process call to {function.__name__}() failed with:\n" + output)
RuntimeError: Child process call to find_binary_dependencies() failed with:
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 35, in pywin32error
    yield
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
    return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_dll.py", line 23, in _LoadLibraryEx
    result = check_null(
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_util.py", line 81, in __call__
    self._raise_error(function_name)
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_util.py", line 92, in _raise_error
    raise exception
OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated\_child.py", line 63, in run_next_command
    output = function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 162, in find_binary_dependencies
    return bindepend.Dependencies(binaries, redirects=binding_redirects, xtrapath=extra_libdirs)
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 205, in Dependencies
    for ftocnm, fn in getAssemblyFiles(pth, manifest, redirects):
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 372, in getAssemblyFiles
    for assembly in getAssemblies(pth):
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 326, in getAssemblies
    res = winmanifest.GetManifestResources(pth)
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 979, in GetManifestResources
    return winresource.GetResources(filename, [RT_MANIFEST], names, languages)
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 155, in GetResources
    hsrc = win32api.LoadLibraryEx(filename, 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 42, in LoadLibraryEx
    with _pywin32error():
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\jackp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
    raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (2, 'LoadLibraryEx', 'The system cannot find the file specified')
```

Please could someone let me know how I would solve this or otherwise another method of turning this into an .exe. Thanks

### Update:

I have tried uninstalling my python 3.10 and downloading 3.7 instead, as I saw somewhere that PyInstaller is incompatible with 3.8 and above, but this still didn't work for another reason. So I reinstalled 3.10 (effectively at this point I have uninstalled and reinstalled my python and IDE) and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I have also tried changing the file name to things like "current.py" thinking the use of numbers and/or full stops may be causing an issue.